# ProducerConsumer problem

Tags: c, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to translate the scenario below using threads.

```
procA {
     while (TRUE) {
     
      update(x);
      
     retrieve(y);
      }
     }
     procB {
     while (TRUE) {
     retrieve(x);
     
     update(y);
     
      }
     }
```

Have written the code for this which I have provided below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define WORK_SIZE 10
pthread_mutex_t work_mutex;
int wa1[WORK_SIZE];
int wa2[WORK_SIZE];
void *funA(void *);
void *funB(void *);
int main(){

 pthread_t tid1,tid2;

 if(pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,funA,(void *)wa1))
    perror("pthread_create");
 if(pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,funB,(void *)wa2))
   perror("pthread_create");

 pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2,NULL);

  return 0;
 }


  void *funA(void *ptr){
  int *x=ptr;
   int i=0,j,num;
   //sleep(1);
  while(i<=10){
    num=rand();
   *x=num;
    x+1;
    j=*wa2;
  printf("A: %d\n",j);
    wa2+1;
     i++;
      }
   return NULL;
    }

 void * funB(void *ptr){
   int *y=ptr;
   int a=0,b,num;
    while(a<=10){
     num=rand();
     b=*wa1;
    printf("B: %d\n",b);
     wa1+1;
    *y=num;
    y+1;
    a++;
   }
    return NULL;
   }
```

I am required to implement MUTEX but that will come later into the picture. For now as my per my understanding, both the threads should in progress simultaneously and hence the address pointed by *wa1 and *wa2 should be getting updated simultaneously. It seems I am missing something because of which the output getting generated is :
**Included infinite loop. Updated o/p depicted below(only a part of the output)**

```
A: 1258442020
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
A: 803738656
B: 1317969989
A: 803738656
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
A: 1251276256
B: 1851766329
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
B: 455345464
```

Seems like after the infinite loop, a context switch happens but I am still not clear on the output. The random function should generate a new number but rather the same number is getting repeated. Any suggestions please and how can this be termed as a producer -consumer problem  **How can I implement this problem is a better manner than the one I have implemented**

thanks.

Comment: Make while loops infinite and tell us what the output looks like.

Comment: The random number is only changed by the other process, so only changed when it's active. Also remember that your lines "wa1+1" and "wa2+1" do nothing; they must be "wa1++" to be effective.

Comment: Oh, and wa1 and wa2 are never written to. That's also why these values don't change. Edit: Oh, yes, they are, sorry. This code is too convoluted.

Comment: When i gave it as "wa1++" it was not getting compiled so I changed it to this way. These are basically incrementing  the address pointed to and i was under the impression that &wa1/&wa2 will get updated everytime the loop iterates. Could you please point my mistake here.

Comment: What you have done is like writing `3+1;`. To increment the address in the pointer you have to write `wa1=wa1+1` or `wa1++`

Comment: Did wa2++ and wa2=wa2+1 but it gives this error : 
2prod_cons.c:51: incompatible types in assignment

Answer (score 0):

The ten iteration are just so few that they are handled before a context switch can happen, so you wouldn't see any concurrency. I'm sorry that I can't really tell anything from your code because it lacks indentation, comments and good variable names.

Comment: Sorry for that, need to perform those activities as well.My bad